# Cordova Camera not working in android phones after building apk with intel xdk

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

When I test my camera project as a USB connected device everything works well. Now I have decided to build the app to generate an apk file using intel xdk. After building and installing the apk on my device on click the camera button, no event is initiated. 
This is my controller:

```
    .controller("IController", function($scope, $cordovaCamera) {
$scope.takePicture = function() {
    var options = { 
        quality : 75, 
        destinationType : Camera.Dest

inationType.DATA_URL, 
                sourceType : Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA, 
                allowEdit : false,
                encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
                targetWidth: 350,
                targetHeight: 350,
                popoverOptions: CameraPopoverOptions,
                correctOrientation: true,
                saveToPhotoAlbum: false
            };

            $cordovaCamera.getPicture(options).then(function(imageData) {
                $scope.imgURI = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
            }, function(err) {
                // An error occured. Show a message to the user
            });
        }
    });
```

And this is my index:

```
<ion-content ng-controller="IController">
    <div class="item item-image">
    <img ng-show="imgURI !== undefined" ng-src="{{imgURI}}" style="max-width: 40%">
    <img ng-show="imgURI === undefined" ng-src="http://placehold.it/300x300" style="max-width: 100%">
    </div>
    <div class="button-bar">
    <button ng-click="takePicture()" class="button icon-left ion-android-camera customIconSound">Take photo</button>
        <button ng-click="takePicture()" class="button button-outline icon-right ion-home customIconSound">Gallery!</button>
    </div>
</ion-content>
```

Please what am I missing. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve my problem using this approach after much trying on different things. I clicked on the XDK Project tabs then clicked the plus sign to "**plugins**" then clicked "**included plugins**" and then checked the "**camera**" checkbox